# Android studio build 2 dependencies containing same package

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, jar, android-gradle-plugin

I have two packages as dependencies in an Android project: A and B, defined in `build.gradle` as following:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'dependency-A'

    compile files('libs/dependency-B.jar')
}
```

I can build the project, however when trying to run it I get the following error:

> :app:compileDebugSources
>   :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcommon/package/in/both/Dependencies;
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:579)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:535)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:517)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
>       at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>   FAILED
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

How can I exclude common package or do something about it, so that it would build and run correctly?

I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1, buildToolsVersion 23.0.2, com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found easy and clean solution yet, however here is one possible workaround (if decompiling of any dependency is not prohibited):

1. Remove common package/classes from `dependency-A`: unzip .jar file, remove the files, zip the remaining  files back in the jar;
2. Decompile `dependency-B` with any java-decompiler, e.g. with [this one](https://github.com/fesh0r/fernflower);
3. Add decompiled `dependency-B` `.java` files as part of your module sources or maybe as a separate one;
4. Build and run the project.